# Novel in which the protagonist receives a new name when coming of age

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have been trying to remember a novel I read somewhere in the (late?) 1990s. It was about a boy living in an isolated village. He treks into the forest to receive a new name (true name?) from an old venerated hermit. It is a custom of the village for those coming of age to do so. The name is meant to be kept secret. Shortly after this event is when the true story begins as, if I remember correctly, the boy leaves the village. I think he becomes a soldier of some sort?

I have vague recollections of a wolf, and a large wall. The forest is also prominent in my memory, but that may have only been early in the story.

I don't know if it was a stand-alone novel or the first of a series.

Comment: I've edited so the media is present in the title to make it clearer before a thorough read, this is in accordance to (in)formal policies on the matter. You also have a nice description of the start of the book but do you remember much else from after that point that you can [edit] in?

Comment: Getting a new true name at "adulthood" and keeping your true name secret is pretty broad.  Do you recall any other plot details?

Comment: @ZeissIkon My memory seems to stop short. I'll add anything that I can think of as I remember it. I'm not absolutely sure I ever finished the story. I know it's not a lot of detail but I was hoping it was enough to stay open; It's been driving me insane trying to remember haha. I did check the meta about story-ID.

Comment: Ursula K. Le Guin's _"A wizard of Earthsea"_? The _true name_ hint fits, and the _wall_ too, but I remember no wolf ...

Comment: @lfurini The wolf could be a confound, I was just trying to include any detail that came to mind when trying to recall the story.

Comment: If you had read it later I would suggest Edain's meeting with Father Wolf under the Forever Trees might be a solution but _The Sunrise Lands_ wasn't published until 2007.

Comment: @Ash It was well before I graduated from High School :) Thanks, though

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in this story that's science fiction or fantasy

Comment: @lfurini The hermit comes to the boy in _A Wizard of Earthsea_ doesn't he?

Comment: @Ash After his naming day, Ged's grandmother sends him to Re Albi to learn from the wizard, and he stays there for several years.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Yes but Ogden? the wizard who apprentices Ged, who is usually a hermit, comes to the village for Ged's name-day rather than Ged going to the hermit to be named, or am I remembering a different story?

Comment: Can you please edit in any information that would mike it clear this was a SF or fantasy story? Not only would it help narrow things down, it would be the difference between this being left open, and being closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Ash I could be confounding both events. This was a long time ago. It seems familar and I'm looking into it.

Comment: @RDFozz It was definitely fantasy. I've never encountered true names in sci-fi. The tag explicitly said not to use it unless it was specifically about the genre itself.

Comment: @Jason_c_o - the issue is that, based on the current description, this could be the biography of a native American. The concept of a true name in and of itself doesn't necessarily make the story fantasy. Certainly the story *could* be fantasy, but it would require something more to show it was actually fantasy.

Comment: Presence of some sort of magic (which has actual effects, although they might be subtle or ambiguous), monsters, prophecies (which have actual effects), or supernatural aspects like ghosts are all good things to note for qualifying as fantasy.

Comment: Even if it is fantasy, this is a really common trope. I can think of 4 or 5 novels offhand that fit this, starting with *Talon of the Silver Hawk* and others.